# How to create multiple field in swing and use the value in a for loop

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a user interface where the user can select the caracteristic of each pizza he wants.
And I would like to be abl to use the value enter by said user.

So here's my code:

```
                JPanel panelComm2 = new JPanel();
                String[] crust = Crust.names();
                String[] size  = Size.names();
                String[] drink = Drink.names();


                Box verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
                for(int i=0;i<nbPizza;i++){
                    Box horizontalBox =  Box.createHorizontalBox();
                    JLabel crustJLabel = new JLabel("Crust Pizza "+ (i+1)+": ");
                    horizontalBox.add(crustJLabel);
                    JComboBox comboCrust = new JComboBox(crust);
                    horizontalBox.add(comboCrust);

                    JLabel sizeJLabel = new JLabel("Size Pizza "+ (i+1)+": ");
                    horizontalBox.add(sizeJLabel);
                    JComboBox comboSize = new JComboBox(size);
                    horizontalBox.add(comboSize);
                    verticalBox.add(horizontalBox);
                }
                for (int j=0;j<nbDrink;j++){
                    Box horizontalBox =  Box.createHorizontalBox();
                    JLabel drinkJLabel = new JLabel("Drink "+ (j+1) +": ");
                    horizontalBox.add(drinkJLabel);
                    JComboBox comboChooseDrink = new JComboBox(drink);
                    horizontalBox.add(comboChooseDrink);
                    verticalBox.add(horizontalBox);
                }

                panelComm2.add(verticalBox);

                int p = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panelComm2, "Select option",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        null, options2, options2[0]);
                if (p == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    // Here I want to store the value enter by the user in the comboBox
                    // Without a for, I would do this
                    //
                    // String crust1 = comboCrust().getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //
                    //But comboCrust don't exist anymore cause it exist only in the for
                    System.out.println("To do");
                }
```

You can see I generate my interface within some for loop, the size of those loop, is depending of some variable (define before by the user)

A JComboBox is created for chosing either the 'Crust','Size' or 'Drink'. (All three are enumerations)

And the inteface is organized with the help of "Box" horizontal and vertical. Which I put in my main panel "panelComm2" also use to make a JoptionPane at the end.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: User interface]

Yet with the way I've built my interface, I can't get the information selected by the user.

I'm looking for a way to add variables for each field of the interface, so that I could use them when the user clicks on 'Ok'.

Comment: You need to maintain a reference to the fields you want to inspect later.  One solution might be to put them all into arrays.  Another might be to create a custom `JPanel` which contains the basic properties for each row of information, which can then be asked about the selected properties or make other decisions, which you could then place instances of into an array

Comment: I did quite understand the Jpanel idea. But the array thing works really well.
I was to focused on my idea to make variables

Comment: The basic idea is to "encapsulate" the functionality you want into a single, re-usable component

Comment: use Model or Model's

Answer (score 0):

I give up on the idea of making variables for each field, and use array of JcomboBox define prior the 'for' loop.

```
JComboBox[] arrayComboCrust = new JComboBox[nbPizza];
JComboBox[] arrayComboSize = new JComboBox[nbPizza];
JComboBox[] arrayComboDrink = new JComboBox[nbDrink];
```

And then within the loop I define the value of the array:

```
arrayComboCrust[i]=comboCrust;
```

And I set up a new 'for' loop to in my JOptionPane to read the value I wanted

Thanks to MadProgrammer